# How to get the administrator role id to assign new permissions?

Tags: 7, users

In my module I'm creating new permissions that I want by default also assigned to the Drupal admin user.

I know how to assign new permissions to a role, but I don't know how to get the Drupal administrator role id. In the database the rid for administrator is 3, but can I rely on that being always the case? I'm using Drupal 7.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, new modules always apply permissions to the administrator role defined on `admin/config/people/accounts`. But only if you install the module. So disabling, uninstalling and installing should grant the the permissions to the admin user as well. (Or if someone else installs the module fresh.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unless you install Drupal in your custom installation profile and modify the administrator role there, the `rid` or administrator will be always `3`.
Or you could just do a [`db_query()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7) on `role` table to return the `rid` of administrator as:

```
$result = db_query("SELECT rid FROM {role} where name like :id",array(':id' => 'administrator'));
$admin_rid = $result->fetchField(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider that the administrator role may have a different name than `administrator` or may have a different role ID.

Drupal 7 has a configuration available at Account Settings page: **Administrator role**

[image: Administrator role]

The value is stored in variable named `user_admin_role`.

```php
$admin_rid = variable_get('user_admin_role');
```

After getting the role ID, you can do pretty much anything you need with it.